# apcahe can't start in xampp ver 1.7.4

Tags: php, apache

I have installed `XAMPP ver 1.7.4.` since yesterday, It works fine. but now can't able to turn on apache in XAMPP control panel.

I followed related to this post in stackoverflow. so i have been changed port number in httpd.conf. still i can't get it.

My **XAMPP** control panel page look this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaakD.jpg

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what version of xampp server you are using?.

Comment: what you meant about completely?

Comment: Ok sorry. can you see SCM button in the control panel?

Comment: Or Services button (for higher version WS)

Comment: @SilverBullet: what i do in that?

Comment: Are you using skype? and what message is shown in control panel when you starts apache.

Comment: @ArshadHussain: It shows "windows could not start the apache2.2 on local computer". and i m not using skpe.

Comment: From ym experience usually only two things obstruct xampp apache from starting on windows: skype port (80), and www publishing service. Make sure you turn that off.

Comment: @GytisŠk: what is www publishing service

Comment: Comouter > Manage > Services and Applications > World Wide Web Publishing Service > Propertie > Startup Type > Disabled > Apply

Comment: @GytisŠk: under services and applications didn't have World Wide Web Publishing Service

Answer (score 0):

Clicking over the service management button, you can see the list of services and its statuses. Click over the apache and at the left pane you can see the start link.

Click that start link. It still not started then some service have using the port 80, most probably Skype. If skype opened already, do exit and then start apache

Comment: which means some other service right now consuming the port. Dont change port number manually in conf file that will lead some other cause later. Try finding that service and stop.

Comment: just rename the xampp folder to some other name in c directory

Comment: Open task manager. there you can see the apache running already. do end process and try

Comment: somewhere the files in xampp should be opened already, or apache must be running.